# VBS Remove Readonly attribute recursivelty

Tags: recursion, vbscript, attributes, wsh

I'm very new to VBS and experimenting with removing the read only attribute from a directory recursively.

It's removing the read only attribute for files but not for the directories. Also The files within these directories seem to have lost their associated program link and are now all showing as an unregistered file type. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: I can see why the files have lost their associations now. It's because the . which separates the name from the extension has been removed! Doh! Ideally I'd like to rename the filename only.

```
re.Pattern =  "[_.]"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

RemoveReadonlyRecursive("T:\Torrents\")

Sub RemoveReadonlyRecursive(DirPath)
    ReadOnly = 1
    Set oFld = FSO.GetFolder(DirPath)

    For Each oFile in oFld.Files
        If oFile.Attributes AND ReadOnly Then
            oFile.Attributes = oFile.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
        End If
        If re.Test(oFile.Name) Then
            oFile.Name = re.Replace(oFile.Name, " ")
        End If
    Next
    For Each oSubFld in oFld.SubFolders
        If oSubFld.Attributes AND ReadOnly Then
            oSubFld.Attributes = oSubFld.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
        End If
        If re.Test(oSubFld.Name) Then
            oSubFld.Name = re.Replace(oSubFld.Name, " ")
        End If

        RemoveReadonlyRecursive(oSubFld.Path)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to automate a repeatable action by a script. Why don't you use the `attrib` command to do that for you:

```
attrib -r "T:\Torrents\*.*" /S
```

You can place that in a batch file if you want to attach it to an clickable icon.

EDIT:
To run it from VBScript silently:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "attrib -r ""T:\Torrents\*.*"" /S", 0, true)
```

EDIT2:
To replace everything except the last period, use a regular expression like:

```
filename = "my file.name.001.2012.extension"
Set regEx = New RegExp
' Make two captures:
' 1. Everything except the last dot
' 2. The last dot and after that everything that is not a dot
regEx.Pattern = "^(.*)(\.[^.]+)$"     ' Make two captures:

' Replace everything that is a dot in the first capture with nothing and append the second capture        
For each match in regEx.Execute(filename)
    newFileName = replace(match.submatches(0), ".", "") & match.submatches(1)
Next
```

Comment: That does sound like a great idea but the script does a bit more besides the above and I'm trying to avoid a command prompt window.

Comment: I added a script to run it silently from VBScript. It does wait until the command is ready, if you want to go on with your script (and do not want to wait), change the last parameter from `true` to `false`.

Comment: This is not a bribe, is it? Searching for patterns is best done with regular expressions. I added the code in the second edit. Enjoy! (This is a respons to a comment that is now deleted, it is about concerning the replacement of all periods in a filename without the last one for the extention)

Comment: Yep it was a bare faced bribe and not part of the original question so I deleted it. It seems to have worked though so cudos to you :)