# Make all files and a folder and all subfolders read only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder that contains multiple folders which contain multiple files.  I would like to use a macro from excel 2010 to make all of the files in all of the folders read only.  I tried the code below but as I step through it I find that `sFile` never gets populated with a string and intern does not work.

```
Sub setFileReadOnly()
   Dim sPath As String
   Dim sFile As String

   sPath = "c:\temp\"

   sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.*")

   Do Until sFile = ""
      SetAttr sPath & sFile, vbReadOnly
      sFile = Dir
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to recurse on all sub-folders?

Comment: @cheezsteak: I would guess that was the intent with *make all of the files in all of the folders*.

Comment: http://www.excelforum.com/l/665427-asdf.html

Comment: @James: take a look at [SO: 15204777/vbs-remove-readonly-attribute-recursivelty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204777/vbs-remove-readonly-attribute-recursivelty) which does the opposite of what you want, using VBScript and the [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx)...

Answer (score 3):

You need a recursive procedure for this and another procedure that calls it to start the process. The `Dir` function should not be used recursively. Try this code, after adding a reference (Tools -> References) to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "c:\temp\"

    Call setFileReadOnly(sPath)

End Sub

Sub setFileReadOnly(sPath As String)

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sSubFolder As String
    Dim fsoObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim folderObject As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fileObject As Scripting.File

    Set fsoObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    For Each folderObject In fsoObject.GetFolder(sPath).SubFolders
        Debug.Print folderObject.Path
        Call setFileReadOnly(folderObject.Path & "\")
    Next folderObject

    For Each fileObject In fsoObject.GetFolder(sPath).Files
        Debug.Print sPath & fileObject.Name
        SetAttr sPath & fileObject.Name, vbReadOnly
    Next fileObject

End Sub
```

I have left in the `Debug.Print` statements.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with the FileSystemObject in the scripting runtime. You'll need to either add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime or change the code to use late binding.  After you set your starting folder, you can easily recurse all sub folders:

```
Sub SetFilesReadOnly(Optional location As Folder)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    If location Is Nothing Then
        Set location = fso.GetFolder("C:\Temp")
    End If

    Dim target As File
    For Each target In location.Files
        target.Attributes = target.Attributes + ReadOnly
    Next target

    Dim directory As Folder
    For Each directory In location.SubFolders
        SetFilesReadOnly directory
    Next directory
End Sub
```